# Is it safe to paint the Raspberry Pi PCB and microchips to give it a different color, and if so, are there recommended products?

Tags: hardware, cooling

In the [O'Reilly book "Raspberry Pi Hacks"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029083.do) there is 
Hack 40 "Make Your Pi Water-Resistant (Without a Case)" in which they describe how they make a Raspberry Pi temporarily water-resistant using Rustoleum's [NeverWet](http://www.neverwet.com/) paint.

Then I got my hands on a (not so limited?) [matte-black Pimoroni Pibow Midnight case](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/pibow-midnight). But as can be seen on [this image](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0174/1800/products/Pibow_Midnight_2_of_4_1024x1024.JPG) the green PCB of the Raspberry Pi shines through. So I wondered how it might look like if I'd paint the Raspberry Pi in matte-black, too.

Hence my question is: Is it safe to paint the Raspberry Pi in a different color and if so, is there (preferably matte-black) color/varnish/coating which is (preferably explicitly) non-conductive and could be used to give a Raspberry Pi PCB and its chips a different color?

So far I only found [this thread](https://www.hidplanet.com/forums/forum/general-discussion/leds/34039-painting-nonconductive-side-of-pcb-s-to-hide-ugly-pcb-color) on the web but most replies seem to be about wrapping stuff in tape to hide the PCB. Another [web page](http://www.electronics-project-design.com/ConformalCoating.html) touches the topic, but only lists material, no actual product or so.

Side questions: Anyone did something like this already? Any side effects on the cooling?

Comment: there will be several difficulties here, firstly finding a paint that is non conductive, black paints usually use some form of carbon as a pigment which can cause you an issue, you will need to find one that doesn't. secondly you'll need to make sure the paint doesn't get into any of the connectors or they won't work. and lastly, if you paint directly over the processor etc you will add to the thermal impedance, i.e. it will get hotter, maybe only a little, but it will. your best bet would be to mask all the connectors and the tops of the CPU/memory before painting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most paints/coatings are non-conductive. You can always paint a small piece of cardboard and check the resistance with a multimeter when it dries out, before painting your RPi.

Just stay away from water-based coatings, since trace amounts of water can penetrate the PCB and cause corrosion. Go for acrylic paints or similar. If you have a girlfriend, she might have a jar of black nail polish she doesn't like any more. I have used cheap nail polish on electronics and have never come across a conductive one.

Side effects on cooling will be practically non-existant, in fact, you are likely to be better off with paint than with a bare PCB. Pretty much any paint has better thermal conductivity than air, and black is great for radiating the heat away.